# JNativeInterface prevent JNI from printing to console

Tags: java

I was testing the JNativeInterface's sample code from the site :

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

            if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ESCAPE) {
                    GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
            }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            }
            catch (NativeHookException ex) {
                    //System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
                    //System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

                    System.exit(1);
            }

            //Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
            GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```

The code by itself functions, but constantly displays output whever the mouse is moved. This is annoying as it spams the console reducing the visbility of other more important output. I isolated this to the GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook(); but this appears as it is a call to the JNI, so I'm unsure of how to prevent it from displaying. Any suggestions?

Comment: Generating output to the console appears to be the purpose of this code.  If that is not what you want to do with the information acquired then modify it to do something other than System.out.println()

Comment: Nope, I guess i could have been a bit more clear. This class only displays KeyEvents. My issue is that it constantly displays mouse events right from the JNI level.

Comment: Maybe you can register some kind of similar mouse listener that is silent.  Or grep -v the output to exclude mouse messages.

Comment: I decided to use a different library. Well, I guess that's one way to drive potential users away :P